# How to send data from service class to main activity class?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I am developing an android Application called Call recorder. The recording is done in background running service class. Now how can I received call info from service class to main activity class to show on UI ?

Comment: you should consider selecting an answer for this question

Answer (score 0):

You can use an BroadcastReceiver and pass data...etc, here are some tutorials whit brodcastreceiver :

[BrodcastReceiver link](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/11/pass-data-from-service-to-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of communication based on requirement and scenario: You can communicate using:

Binder,
Messanger,
AIDL

Following link will give you details and ways of implementing them:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

You can also use custom broascast receiver for this purpose.

I think in your case you can use Binder..

Answer (score 0):

- Use a messenger to send the Message from the Service on
  onHandleIntent() method
- Receive it with a handler

  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html